# How to insert a character at a certain position in all rows using R

Tags: r, regex

Hey I have a column of birth dates in this format:

| dob |
| --- |
| 19881011 |
| 19590223 |
| 19860407 |
| 19710921 |
| 19640213 |

I need to edit the column to this format:

| dob |
| --- |
| 1988-10-11 |
| 1959-02-23 |
| 1986-04-07 |
| 1971-09-21 |
| 1964-02-13 |

I came across similar problems being solved with gsub and regex but was able to apply it to my problem. Can someone recommend a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The `ymd` from `lubridate` can correctly parse it to `Date` class if it is numeric or character

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df1 <- df1 %>%
    mutate(dob = ymd(dob))
```

-output

```
df1
#     dob
#1 1988-10-11
#2 1959-02-23
#3 1986-04-07
#4 1971-09-21
#5 1964-02-13
```

---

It is not a regex problem as converting to `Date` class is straightforward with `as.Date` and `format` argument.  If we need a regex option

```
sub("(....)(..)(..)", "\\1-\\2-\\3", df1$dob)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(dob = c(19881011L, 19590223L, 19860407L, 19710921L, 
19640213L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R option using `as.Date`

```
transform(
  df,
  dob = as.Date(as.character(dob), "%Y%m%d")
)
```

gives

```
         dob
1 1988-10-11
2 1959-02-23
3 1986-04-07
4 1971-09-21
5 1964-02-13
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(dob = c(19881011L, 19590223L, 19860407L, 19710921L, 
19640213L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```